# TypeError when working with lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, syntax

I am trying to adapt the [code](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/LSTM_tsc/blob/master/tsc_model.py) to my own data.

```
DATA=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
ind=[1,3,6,2]
ratio=[2,3]
DATA[ind[:ratio[0]],1:]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Any idea why? (I don't quite understand what the `,1:]` supposed to do)

Comment: please provide piece of executable code and do not use external links as support - we want to have minimal code pasted here

Comment: `ind[:ratio[0]],1:` is a tuple. It looks like you're coming in with experience in R. If so, I'd recommend looking into `pandas` or `numpy`, which would afford you this kind of syntax

Comment: The code you are working off of is working with `numpy` arrays, not Python **lists** which you have here. There is a *huge* difference. For example, `numpy` arrays support multi-dimensional indexing, which is what you are trying to do here. Lists don't.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga which part should be numpy array? I have changed them all to numpy arrays with numpy.asarray() and now I get ´IndexError: too many indices for array'

Comment: Yes becaue you are using multidimensional indexing but your `list`s will be converted into one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: If you don't understand the code you're looking at, get an understanding first before you try to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From line [36](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/LSTM_tsc/blob/master/tsc_model.py#L36), it seems that `Data` is not a list but is actually an array:

`DATA = np.concatenate((data_train,data_test_val),axis=0)`

And as you can see in numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), `concatenate()` returns an array not a list.

Comment: thank you. had to convert DATA to numpy array and reshape. Now it works fine (assumed it was a list)